cmake error ：CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:271 (message):
cmake version：3.22.1
ros: melodic in Ubuntu18.04
when I "catkin_make"， and report an error as follow:

-- Using these message generators:
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:271 (message):
Could not find 'share/std_msgs/cmake/std_msgs-msg-paths.cmake' (searched in
'/home/mandy/ross/test_ws/devel').
Call Stack (most recent call first):
wpb_home/wpb_home_behaviors/CMakeLists.txt:80 (generate_messages)

Actually， I have tryed to "catkin_make" other project ，and if the CMakeList.txt of the projet have the part of “generate_messages”， the error as follow also occur.
The CMakeList.txt is as follow:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(wpb_home_behaviors)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/ros/melodic" ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O3")

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp rospy std_msgs 
  pcl_conversions pcl_ros 
  cv_bridge image_transport tf 
  sensor_msgs geometry_msgs std_msgs visualization_msgs 
  image_geometry 
  message_generation
  move_base_msgs actionlib 
)

## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
add_message_files(
  FILES
  Coord.msg
  Rect.msg
 )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
)

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if your package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES wpb_home_behaviors
 CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs message_runtime
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
  include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/wpb_home_behaviors.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
# add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/wpb_home_behaviors_node.cpp)

## Rename C++ executable without prefix
## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_wpb_home_behaviors.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)

add_executable(wpb_home_grab_server
  src/wpb_home_grab_server.cpp
)
add_dependencies(wpb_home_grab_server ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(wpb_home_grab_server
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(wpb_home_pass_server
  src/wpb_home_pass_server.cpp
)
add_dependencies(wpb_home_pass_server ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(wpb_home_pass_server
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(wpb_home_objects_3d
  src/wpb_home_objects_3d.cpp
)
add_dependencies(wpb_home_objects_3d ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(wpb_home_objects_3d
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(wpb_home_grab_action
  src/wpb_home_grab_action.cpp
)
add_dependencies(wpb_home_grab_action ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(wpb_home_grab_action
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(wpb_home_face_detect_3d
  src/wpb_home_face_detect_3d.cpp
)
add_dependencies(wpb_home_face_detect_3d ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(wpb_home_face_detect_3d
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(wpb_home_place_action
  src/wpb_home_place_action.cpp
)
add_dependencies(wpb_home_place_action ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(wpb_home_place_action
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

the package.xml is as follow:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>wpb_home_behaviors</name>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <description>The wpb_home_behaviors package</description>

  <!-- One maintainer tag required, multiple allowed, one person per tag -->
  <!-- Example:  -->
  <!-- <maintainer email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</maintainer> -->
  <maintainer email="zhangwanjie@6-robot.com">Zhang Wanjie</maintainer>


  <!-- One license tag required, multiple allowed, one license per tag -->
  <!-- Commonly used license strings: -->
  <!--   BSD, MIT, Boost Software License, GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 -->
  <license>BSD</license>

  <url type="website">http://www.6-robot.com</url>


  <!-- Url tags are optional, but multiple are allowed, one per tag -->
  <!-- Optional attribute type can be: website, bugtracker, or repository -->
  <!-- Example: -->
  <!-- <url type="website">http://wiki.ros.org/wpb_home_behaviors</url> -->


  <!-- Author tags are optional, multiple are allowed, one per tag -->
  <!-- Authors do not have to be maintainers, but could be -->
  <!-- Example: -->
  <!-- <author email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</author> -->


  <!-- The *depend tags are used to specify dependencies -->
  <!-- Dependencies can be catkin packages or system dependencies -->
  <!-- Examples: -->
  <!-- Use depend as a shortcut for packages that are both build and exec dependencies -->
  <!--   <depend>roscpp</depend> -->
  <!--   Note that this is equivalent to the following: -->
  <!--   <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend> -->
  <!--   <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend> -->
  <!-- Use build_depend for packages you need at compile time: -->
  <!--   <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend> -->
  <!-- Use build_export_depend for packages you need in order to build against this package: -->
  <!--   <build_export_depend>message_generation</build_export_depend> -->
  <!-- Use buildtool_depend for build tool packages: -->
  <!--   <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend> -->
  <!-- Use exec_depend for packages you need at runtime: -->
  <!--   <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend> -->
  <!-- Use test_depend for packages you need only for testing: -->
  <!--   <test_depend>gtest</test_depend> -->
  <!-- Use doc_depend for packages you need only for building documentation: -->
  <!--   <doc_depend>doxygen</doc_depend> -->
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>libpcl-all-dev</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl_ros</build_depend>
  <build_depend>visualization_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>
  <build_depend>actionlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>

  <run_depend>libpcl-all</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>tf</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl_ros</run_depend>
  <run_depend>visualization_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>cv_bridge</run_depend>
  <run_depend>actionlib</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <!-- <run_depend>message_generation</run_depend> -->
  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->

  </export>
</package>

can anyone help me?

Seems like you are getting an error similar to this. Can you try echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and if that doesn't contain the path to the ROS installation, try adding it by using export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:/opt/ros/melodic
